# Foreign key and the n-to-n relation

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Let's say I have these sql tables:
    a) **book**
    b) **customer**
    c) **borrow_history** (book_id, customer_id ... )

I can define two referencing foreign keys (on delete cascade) from **borrow_history**, referencing **book** and **customer**, so:

- **borrow_history** records connected to **book** will be deleted when book was be deleted.
- **borrow_history** records connected to **customer** will be deleted when customer was deleted.

But how Do I define foreign keys in a way, that **customer** will be deleted when he has no **borrow_history** connected to him, so deleting a **book** could recursively delete also **customer**?

Is it possible, or do I have to use triggers?

Comment: A customer can pre-exist when a book (and its borrowing_history) comes into existence but when when that book (and its borrowing_history) ceases to exist the customer also ceases to exist? That sounds odd.

Comment: The goal is to create the customer and it's first borrow history to be made at the same time, in other words, the customer can't pre exsist, intended invariant is there can't be customer at any time that isn't connected to some borrow history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use triggers for that.

Anyway user should NOT be deleted only in case he hasn't got any books - other factors like last activity date is important.

I would write a script (and run it with CRON) to delete users without any borrow_history with more than N days from their last action.

And another hint - foreign key in borrow_history pointing books should be set to ON DELETE RESTRICT. If book is borrowed (or was borrowed) it should NOT be deleted

Comment: Thanks, btw I'm not running a book shop :), this was just simple example of n-to-n relation, in reality, I really need to delete recursively all the data that are not connected by the relation anymore.